# How to make GIT ignore my changes

Tags: git

Although the title seems similar to previous questions, I could not find the solution to to my Simple case:

- I committed to my branch 'ABCD' : `git commit -a   .....`
- Then decided to visit a previous commit so : `git checkout 2387687326487`
- Here I made some changes which was for testing purpose only, and I don't want to keep them
- I am done, I want to get back to my latest commit(again:ignoring changes whcih i made to the old commit) : the command `git checkout 'ABCD'` gives error:

> Your local changes to the following files will be overwritten by checkout....please commit or stash...

while I don't want to commit or stash or whatever. I just want to go back home :) what should I do please?

Comment: By ignore, you seem to mean "silently discard when changing checkouts or branches." Do I read your question correctly? Ignore has a more specialized meaning to me in source control world; specifically: "exclude ignored files from this (and/or future) commit(s)."

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you are sure that you don't want to keep your changes, the following line will do :

```
git checkout -f 'ABCD'
```

Option '-f' stands for force.

Answer (score 92):

Using just

```
git checkout .
```

will discard any uncommitted changes in the current directory (the dot means current directory).

**EDIT** in response to @GokulNK:

If you want to keep those changes for future use, you have 2 options:

- `git stash`: this will save those changes in a stack. You can apply the changes to your working copy later using `git stash pop`
- `git diff > changes.patch`: This will save those changes to the file `changes.patch`. If you want to apply them to your working copy you can do so: `git apply changes.patch`.

Comment: Is there a way to save those changes to a file before doing the git checkout .

Comment: By far the simplest option!

Answer (score 18):

To undo local changes and go back to the state from the commit you can:

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: Is it same as `git reset --hard HEAD` ?

Comment: @alper Yes, `HEAD` is the default, so it is the same whether you add it explicitly or omit it.

Answer (score 14):

Apart from the mentioned solutions you can stash the changes

```
git stash
```

Checkout your branch

```
git checkout 'ABCD'
```

And eventually, when you are sure that you don't need anything from the stashed changes, and have checked twice with `gitk` or `gitg`, throw away the stash:

```
git stash drop
```

That is my preferred way, as it is safer.

Comment: This is the way I do it as well, safe way

Answer (score 10):

If anyone wants to ignore changes on git but keep them on local you can use :

`$ git update-index --assume-unchanged <filepath>`

Comment: +1 because it answers the title of the question. But the text of the question has nothing to do with the title.